# Referring to CSS Stylesheets in Python Code

Tags: python, html, css

I'm working on an automated email project that gives me my daily revenue from my passive income investments. I have gotten all the automation to work and now I am working on the email structure. I am having trouble with the CSS elements showing up on my email. Here is the relevant code.

```
def send_mail(text=" ", subject=('PKs Daily Overview ' + date), from_email='PKBot <piercedailymail@gmail.com>', to_emails=None, html= """ 
<head>
  <link href="C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\normalize.cs" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\taegans-groovy-site.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pricing-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title-block">
        <h1 class="heading">Pierce&#x27;s <span class="text-span">Passive Income Breakdown</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-wrap">
        <div class="pricing-column-02">
          <div class="pricing-card purple">
            <div class="div-block">
              <h3 class="pricing-h3 white">Helium</h3><img src="images/helium-hnt-logo.png" loading="lazy" width="53" id="w-node-_3b1efe47-cc49-dccf-fdc4-c9ae7d3a64ca-c7f2d992" srcset="images/helium-hnt-logo-p-500.png 500w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-800.png 800w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-1080.png 1080w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-1600.png 1600w, images/helium-hnt-logo.png 2000w" sizes="53px" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-details-wrap">
              <div class="pricing white"><h1>${strtotal}</h1></div>
              <div class="pricing white"><h1 style="color:purple;">${strtotal}</h1></div>
              <div class="date white">last 24 hours</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-check-wrap">
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Expert Foggy Perch:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Macho Carrot Orca:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
              </div>
              <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Sneaky Chrome Dog:</strong></p>
              <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
            </div>
            <a href="https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9" class="pricing-button white w-button">Open Explorer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
"""
```

It comes out with all the HTML. The code line of `<div class="pricing white"><h1 style="color:purple;">${strtotal}</h1></div>` was just a test for me to see if the CSS would work inline, but I'm still having trouble referencing the stylesheets. Appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference your css files this way since when the email is read from the receiver side, it isn't able the pull the css file from the provided path (because the path store locally on your machine instead of the receiver's). I think one way you can work around this is to paste the entire content of the css file into the html code, inside the `<style>` tag instead using the `<string>.format(<value 1>, ...)` function

```py
def extract_css(css_file_name):
    # return the string content of the CSS file
    with open(css_file_name, 'r') as fl:
        content = fl.read()
    return content

def send_mail(text=" ", subject=('PKs Daily Overview ' + date), from_email='PKBot <piercedailymail@gmail.com>', to_emails=None, html= """
<head>
  <style>
{}
  </style>
  <style>
{}
  </style>
  <style>
{}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pricing-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title-block">
        <h1 class="heading">Pierce&#x27;s <span class="text-span">Passive Income Breakdown</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-wrap">
        <div class="pricing-column-02">
          <div class="pricing-card purple">
            <div class="div-block">
              <h3 class="pricing-h3 white">Helium</h3><img src="images/helium-hnt-logo.png" loading="lazy" width="53" id="w-node-_3b1efe47-cc49-dccf-fdc4-c9ae7d3a64ca-c7f2d992" srcset="images/helium-hnt-logo-p-500.png 500w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-800.png 800w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-1080.png 1080w, images/helium-hnt-logo-p-1600.png 1600w, images/helium-hnt-logo.png 2000w" sizes="53px" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-details-wrap">
              <div class="pricing white"><h1>${strtotal}</h1></div>
              <div class="pricing white"><h1 style="color:purple;">${strtotal}</h1></div>
              <div class="date white">last 24 hours</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-check-wrap">
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Expert Foggy Perch:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Macho Carrot Orca:</strong></p>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-check">
                <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
              </div>
              <p class="pricing-text white"><strong>Sneaky Chrome Dog:</strong></p>
              <p class="pricing-text white _2">$8.00</p>
            </div>
            <a href="https://explorer.helium.com/accounts/13pm9juR7WPjAf7EVWgq5EQAaRTppu2EE7ReuEL9jpkHQMJCjn9" class="pricing-button white w-button">Open Explorer</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  """):

    # html with stylesheet code included
    sent_html = html.format(
            extract_css('C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\normalize.css'),
            extract_css('C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\taegans-groovy-site.webflow.css'),
            extract_css('C:\\Users\\kings\\PythonProjects\\DailyEmail\\css\\webflow.css'),
            strtotal='some string')
    print(sent_html)
    # Do something
```

Comment: I run into a ton of problems when it comes to me pasting the entire CSS files into the HTML code. You're saying it is the receiver side not being able to have access to the CSS files as they are stored locally. Is there a way I can just print the html file that has the CSS references as they would already be stored?

Comment: What is the problems you are having when pasting the css files into HTML code? I don't think you can print the rendered html with CSS reference as the html is only rendered by the browser when receiver opens it

Comment: It gives me /n KeyErrors for all of the CSS attributes.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the code you tried with this approach and the full error message? I think that might help with debugging the issue